# CodingBat : LoneSum optimization

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I have completed this exercise on `codingbat` successfully, but I want to know is there a better/faster or more elegant solution?

Given 3 int values, a b c, returns their sum. However, if one of the values is the same as another of the values, it does not count towards the sum.

loneSum(1, 2, 3) → 6
loneSum(3, 2, 3) → 2
loneSum(3, 3, 3) → 0

```
public int loneSum(int a, int b, int c)  
{ 
    int sum = a + b + c;
    if ( a == b) { sum = sum - a - b; }
    if ( a == c) { sum = sum - a - c; }
    if( b == c) { sum = sum - b - c; }
    if (( a == b ) && (b==c)) { sum = 0; }
    return sum;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the time ... this seems like less sub ops so might be faster

```
public int loneSum(int a, int b, int c) {
  int sum = 0;
  boolean ab = a != b;
  boolean ac = a != c;
  boolean bc = b != c;
  if(ab  && ac) sum += a;
  if(ab && bc) sum += b;
  if(bc && ac) sum += c;
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code?

```
public static int loneSum(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a == b && b == c) {
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
            c = 0;
        }
        if (a == b) {
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
        }
        if (a == c) {
            a = 0;
            c = 0;
        }
        if (b == c) {
            b = 0;
            c = 0;
        }

        return a + b + c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int loneSum(int a, int b, int c) {
  if ( (a==b) && (b==c) && (c==a) ) return 0;
  else
  {
   if (a==b) return c ;
   if (b==c) return a;
   if (a==c) return b;
   else  return a+b+c;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first loop checks if all elements of the given array are same. In this case, answer is 0. Further code checks if strictly any two of them are equal to each other. In this case they wont be counted to towards the sum. In other words, (since there are only three elements ) excluding two elements, the sum will be equal to the third element. Finally, for default case, we do the sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int loneSum(int a, int b, int c) {

  int sum = a+b+c;

  if (a==b) sum -= a*2;
  if (b==c) sum -= b*2;
  if (c==a) sum -= c*2;
  if (sum<0) sum=0;

  return sum;  
}
```

This take 4 comparisons.

1. Initialize sum to a+b+c
2. Compare numbers to each other and if same, decrease sum by num*2.
3. If multiple IF's are hit (meaning a==b==c), the sum becomes 0. Return 0 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a==b && b==c) return 0;
if (a==b) return c;
if (a==c) return b;
if (b==c) return a;
return a+b+c;
```

Comment: How is this better than the five other answers already provided (one of which was accepted)?

Comment: this is the shortest one with no useless operations

Answer (score 0):

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
  sum=0
    if a==b==c:
        sum=0
    elif a==b:
        sum=c
    elif a==c:
        sum=b
    elif b==c:
        sum=a
    else:
        sum=a+b+c

  return sum
```

This is for python

```
     public int loneSum(int a, int b, int c)  
             { 
              int sum = a + b + c;
              if ( a == b) { sum = c; }
              if ( a == c) { sum = b; }
              if( b == c) { sum = a; }
              if (( a == b ) && (b==c)) { sum = 0; }
              return sum;  
              }
```

This is for java

Comment: Welcome Siri, your answer seems correct, but the question asks for a solution in Java (look at the tags on the left bottom corner), so it doesn't really answer what has been asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I sending you another approach using ternary operators. I hope it can be useful in your exercises and learning process.

```
public int noTeenSum(int a, int b, int c) {
    a =  (a >= 13 && a <= 19) ? (a == 15 || a == 16) ? a : 0 : a;
    b =  (b >= 13 && b <= 19) ? (b == 15 || b == 16) ? b : 0 : b;
    c =  (c >= 13 && c <= 19) ? (c == 15 || c == 16) ? c : 0 : c;

    return a+b+c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier to read

```
    def lone_sum(a, b, c):
         if a == b == c:
             return 0
         if a == b:
             return c
         if b == c:
             return a
         if a == c:
             return b
         else:
              return a + b + c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```
 def lone_sum(a, b, c):

    if a!=b and b!=c and c!=a:
      return a+b+c
    elif a==b==c:
      return 0
    elif a==b:
      return c
    elif b==c:
      return a
    elif c==a: 
      return b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int loneSum(int a, int b, int c) {
  int sum = a+b+c;
  if(a==b)
    sum -= (a+b);
  if(a==c)
    sum -= (a + c);
  if(b==c)
    sum -= (b+c);
  
  return sum > 0? sum: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a six year old question with an accepted answer it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Also code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score -1):

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
    tempSum, arr2 = a+b+c, list(set([a,b,c]))
    if (a==b==c): return 0
    return sum(arr2) - (tempSum - sum(arr2))
```

Comment: This is specifically a Java question. An answer in Python here is not useful to anyone who might come across the same issue seeking help in Java.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the below function :

```
def su(a,b,c):
    total=0
    for x in (a,b,c):
        if x==(x+1):
            y=0
        else:
            y=1
            total+=x*y
    return total
print(su(3,2,3))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it